# Flutter Local Auth Customization

Tags: flutter, authentication, local

I am trying to use local_auth to authenticate users with Biometric Authentication for an App I am building.

I would like to remove or customize the Face ID dialog box. Please look at the Screen shot provided. I would like to either remove the Grey Box that says Face ID or customize it to look prettier.

I have tried the localizedReason tag but it does not show the message.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrEHq.png)

Comment: Sadly, you cannot change the design apple has given specifically for facial recognition. You can however create an alert dialogue to somewhat surround the Face ID and give your information there.

Comment: Thank you Lars, I figured that would be the case but was hoping there was a solution. I’ll take your suggestion to design around the dialog so it looks a part of the page